# Oracle 11g database administration

Tags: oracle11g

Why do the sizes of the Oracle Database block and the Operating System Block differ? I have searched the Oracle website but haven't found a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2):

The database block is a logical unit of storage, and the operating system block is a physical unit of storage. They don't have to be different sizes, but they can be, as long as the logical block size is equal to or larger than, and a multiple of, the physical block size. This allows Oracle to retrieve an optimal amount of data regardless of the underlying hardware, so it can be more efficient and has less overhead.

From the [database concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/logical.htm#i4894):

> ### Data Blocks and Operating System Blocks
>
> At the physical level, database data is stored in disk files made up
>   of operating system blocks. An operating system block is the minimum
>   unit of data that the operating system can read or write. In contrast,
>   an Oracle block is a logical storage structure whose size and
>   structure are not known to the operating system.
>
> ...
>
> The database requests data in multiples of data blocks, not operating
>   system blocks.
>
> When the database requests a data block, the operating system
>   translates this operation into a requests for data in permanent
>   storage. The logical separation of data blocks from operating system
>   blocks has the following implications:
>
> - Applications do not need to determine the physical addresses of data on disk.
> - Database data can be striped or mirrored on multiple physical disks.

The [administration guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/create.htm#ADMIN11106) also says this:

> If the database block size is different from the operating system
>   block size, then ensure that the database block size is a multiple of
>   the operating system block size.
>
> ...
>
> A larger data block size provides greater efficiency in disk and
>   memory I/O (access and storage of data). Therefore, consider
>   specifying a block size larger than your operating system block size
>   if the following conditions exist:
>
> - Oracle Database is on a large computer system with a large amount of memory and fast disk drives. For example, databases controlled by
>     mainframe computers with vast hardware resources typically use a data
>     block size of 4K or greater.
> - The operating system that runs Oracle Database uses a small operating system block size. For example, if the operating system
>     block size is 1K and the default data block size matches this, the
>     database may be performing an excessive amount of disk I/O during
>     normal operation. For best performance in this case, a database block
>     should consist of multiple operating system blocks.